# Question regarding application of chain rule

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

While reading notes, I saw the following and was confused.  I'm assuming that I'm wrong or I'm forgetting something obvious.  I was wondering if someone could explain what I'm missing.

"If $u(x) = v(|x|)$, then
$$u_{x_{i}} = v'(|x|)\frac{x_i}{|x|} , \text{ for } x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}."$$

My question is why is the derivative not:

$$u_{x_{i}} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_i} = v'(|x|)\frac{x}{|x|} x_i?$$
Where does that extra "x" go?  I apologize in advance for asking such a silly question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your function is a composition $u=v\circ q$, where
$$u = v( q ) \atop q(x) = |x| $$

so by the chain rule the derivative is

$$u_{x_{i}} = \frac{d\,v}{d\,q}\cdot\frac{d\,q}{d\,x_i}  = \frac{d\,v}{d\,\color{red}{|x|}}\cdot\frac{d\,\color{red}{|x|}}{d\,x_i} $$

and

$$\frac{d\,|x|}{d\,x_i} = \frac{d\,\sqrt{{x_i}^2 + \dots}}{d\, x_i} = \frac{2x_i}{2\sqrt{{x_i}^2 + \dots}} = \frac {x_i}{|x|}$$

Note the middle '=' above follows from the chain rule, too:
$$\frac{d\,\sqrt{{x_i}^2 + \dots}}{d\, x_i} = \frac{d\,\sqrt{({x_i}^2) + \dots}}{d\, ({x_i}^2)}\cdot \frac{d\,({x_i}^2)}{d\, x_i} = \frac 1{2\sqrt{{x_i}^2 + \dots}}\cdot 2x_i$$

Comment: Oh! Ok, thank you! How does one know when to use $\frac{d}{dx}$ vs $\frac{d}{d|x|}$?

Comment: @DonnieNathanChad I have expanded the answer a bit. Please see is again.